# Microsoft graph subscription API to create subscription fails with Status Code: BadRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, subscription

Microsoft graph subscription API to create subscription to get file change notification has stopped working today. Getting error below now without any code change:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
with POST body as

```
{
    "resource": "users/admin@mytestdomain.onmicrosoft.com/drive/root",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-05-08T18:21:50.110168Z",
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://api1.mytestdomain.com/one-drive/one-drive-realtime-processor",
    "notificationUrl": "https://api.mytestdomain.com/one-drive/one-drive-realtime-processor",
    "clientState": "onedrive-graph-api-subscription-identifier",
}
```

returns following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: The property 'Resource' does not exist on type 'oneDrive.subscription'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.]",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b04d8791-f96f-4a26-a2c2-dd06fa9d1a42",
            "date": "2020-05-05T22:13:02"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems something has changed in graph api.
Link below shows similar error but it was reported 3 years ago:
[Getting 400 Bad Request Error for MSGraph's create subscription api [Error Code - ExtensionError]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304324/getting-400-bad-request-error-for-msgraphs-create-subscription-api-error-code?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C66.7117)

I have tried both v1.0 and beta API versions.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, since 2 hours ago, only for drive-subscriptions (mail is working fine). Please update if you find more info about it.

Comment: this looks like a service issue that's currently under investigation. Other people reported the same problem recently here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8063
Please open support tickets and refer to ICM 187039005 as this helps us understand the impact.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary service issue that is being resolved by the team. I'll keep posting updates on the [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8063).

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been fixed from Microsoft end and now I see Onedrive subscription API working as before for both OneDrive and SharePoint.
Thanks for quick resolution!